# Building data pipeline with Kafka, Storm and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, apache-kafka, monitoring, apache-storm

I have an incoming data stream (data scraped off a website) that needs to go into different systems with different formats. The stream arrives in great detail in JSON format and should be pushed into ElasticSearch but some aggregates of this data should be added to a relational database and even a Graph database.
Would this be a good use case for Kafka / Storm with consumers for ElasticSearch, Neo4J etc. ? Also I want to derive some information for my monitoring system from the initial stream so I might also have a monitoring consumer as well.
This is more an architectural question if it makes sense for this use case to look at something like Kafka and Storm.
Thanks
Philipp

Answer (score 1):

Yes this sound like a good use case Kafka for streaming data and pushing that data in different databases. On the processing side you have multiple options like Storm, Flink, Spark, you can choose one based on your use case

Comment: Thanks Sunil. I have been looking at the docs for Storm and Flink. As a first reaction I would say I like Flink, the examples from the API read very intuitive and I think I could use the window mechanisms quite well. However there are other questions now comparing Flink back to Storm. In Storm you obviously have a topology where you seem to define a chain of things to happen. Am I right in saying that in Flink you would have one program to do a transformation and then feed back into Kafka and another Flink consumer would then potentially consume it and do another transformation ?